# Can't use ImageTk in customtkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# create root windows

root = customtkinter.CTk()
# find image

button_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("icons/bit.ico").resize((20, 20)))

display_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, image=button_1, text="i am dumb", fg_color="red")

display_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

i used the ctkimage but it showed the image including the place where is nothing(sorry for bad english)

i was trying to display a partially transparent color but it showed the whole thing with the side where nothing is drawn when using CTkImage but when i used imageTk from pillow it showed an error

Comment: What error did you see? Can you show us the full error traceback?

Comment: @TheLizzard. Sorry. I wasn't seeing in parameter